# Using a NodeJS/Express api to return a base64 image for the Facebook og:image tag

Tags: node.js, express, facebook-graph-api

I have created a node/express API to return base64 data as an image.

The image loads fine using https://www.example.com/api/resident/59dbd52a7604450012c390ac/image
I have been using this in various pages on the front end for images.

The problem is, when I try to use this data for the og:image tag on Facebook I get an error:
**"Provided og:image URL, https://www.example.com/api/resident/59dbd52a7604450012c390ac/image could not be processed as an image because it has an invalid content type."**

I know that Facebook can see the correct meta tag as when I click "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" it shows the correct tag. When I click the URL provided it shows the image.

The controller in express looks like:

```
export function image(req, res) {
  var base64Data = req.resident.picture;
  var img = new Buffer(base64Data, 'base64');
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
    'Content-Length': img.length
  });
  return res.end(img);
}
```

The tags in the HTML look like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Site">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.com/api/resident/59dbd52a7604450012c390ac/image">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="800">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="800">
```

Comment: a real example would be good, not just a fake url

Comment: Putting your image URL through the Facebook debugger and then using the [See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Flisten.dublindigitalradio.com%2Fapi%2Fresident%2F59dbd52a7604450012c390ac%2Fimage) link indicates that Facebook is receiving an HTML document from your server, and not an actual image.

Comment: Thanks misorude - that's interesting! I don't think my server is returning the HTML however, if you curl the URL provided it's not returning HTML. I do see that Chrome creates a HTML page similar to the one seen by Facebook when you browse to the URL.

Comment: I ended up removing the /image api and moved to cloudinary to host images instead of storing in base64 in Mongo